# How to remove white pixels around transparent png?

Tags: html, css

I have included a transparent png in my Website and it has white pixels on the borders and they look really buggy.

I have double checked that's not the image itself that includes this pixels and also no border is set in CSS.

Would be happy, if anyone knows this issue and can help.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: It must be on the image.. open photoshop and zoom in.

Comment: How did you double-check that the image doesn't contain those pixels? It sure looks like it does. Have you tried layering the image over black to see?

Comment: Jon Uleis, yes it layered it over a black layer, to make sure. There were no white pixels :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use vector applications to create a logo. Like the "Corel Draw". I created your logo for the sample

[image: sample PNG]

Comment: You lost the shadow in the middle, though. ;)

Comment: I changed the sample image

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in CSS.

The white border is included in the image.

The solution is to use an image editor like Photoshop :

- Select the transparent area with the Magic Wand Tool
- Dilate 1px (or more if needed)
- Press delete
- Save as PNG

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Normally I am pretty good with Photoshop and also checked if it is really the image that has the white pixels with a greenscreen. I couldn't see anything. 

The other strange thing is, that there was only black color around it until I removed it with the wand tool. So it's actually not possible that the are white instead of black pixels around it :D

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an image editor such as [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) or [Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html).

If you got this from an artist you can complain to them that their exported image has a white border. Otherwise you'll have to use a brush and erase them yourself, which can be painful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!

I have saved that image for web with a different color space and that caused the issue :/